# How to Fill a binary File with a Given Number?

Tags: linux, file-io, mmap, memcpy

In my system there are a lot of binary files used to store matrices. When a such file is created, it must be filled with some value, i.e. NAN for matrix with `float` numbers. Is there any good solution to speed up this process?

The currently solution is like this: these files are memory-mapped using `mmap()`, so the file is filled by `memcpy` as follows:

```
float v = NAN;
for (i=0; i<n; ++i){
  memcpy(start+i, &v, sizeof(v));
}
```

where `n` is the number of elements in the matrix, `start` is the memory-mapped address.

I use `memcpy` instead of `buff[i] = NAN` because the type of the matrix element can be different.

Would bulk copy help in this case? For example, I can create a buffer filled with NAN in memory, then copy the buffer to the `start`. Is there any suggestion on the size of the buffer?

Comment: Why not just create the buffer *at* `start`, so that it's already part of the file?

Comment: Yap. Good idea. Any suggestion on the size of the buffer?

Comment: Thanks. I have done some tests and bulk copy does help, which the buffer size only has marginal impact on the execution time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I find that actually a buffer size that is smaller than page size can be better. For example, 128 is a bit faster than 4K. Do you have any idea on that?